# Opening two different browser for same test case in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-jvm, serenity-bdd

My test case need to interact with three different system, say system A, B, C.
System A, B can be opened on chrome and IE both,but system C being legacy system, can be opened on IE only.
On System A, I have to enter series of some user data which then redirects us to system B (we are integrating system A & B) within same browser. After performing some action on system B, in order to assert status we have to open system C which is legacy application and can be opened only on IE. 
Now how can I execute my test case in such a way that opening system A, B on chrome and opening system C on IE. 
I am using selenium webdriver with cucumber and serenity

Comment: so all three browsers in different machines at same time? If so, you can do this with selenium grid.

Comment: No, Let me rephrase my question

Comment: Please share your work

Comment: Serenity manage browser session for user and we no need to write any code for opening browser. So I am not getting where should I declare extra browser i.e. IE

Comment: Initiate a new driver with IE. So you will have driver instances. Chrome for system A and B. IE for system C.

Answer (score 1):

QAF supports feature of working with multiple drivers. Since [QAF 2.1.11](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/release_notes.html) additional feature of having muliple driver sessions in the same test  is added

To have multiple driver session in the same thread/test-case

set driver name using QAFTestBase#setDriver("driverName") For instance,

```
TestBaseProvider.instance().get().setDriver("chromeDriver");`
//some steps with chrome driver
TestBaseProvider.instance().get().setDriver("iExplorerDriver");`
//some steps with another chrome driver

TestBaseProvider.instance().get().setDriver("chromeDriver");`
//switch back and do some steps with chrome driver
```

NOTE: If you don't want to quite driver while switch, set `driver.name` property instead of set driver.